# availability of __builtin_bswap16 for signed short?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to do **swapping of 16 bit signed number** .

So I wrote this logic which works fine :

```
// Byte swap signed short
inline int16_t swap_int16( int16_t val )
{
    return (val << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

But I observed that in gcc compiler following swap function is available for unsigned short variable.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

```
Built-in Function: uint16_t __builtin_bswap16 (uint16_t x)
Returns x with the order of the bytes reversed; for example, 0xaabb becomes 0xbbaa. Byte here always means exactly 8 bits. .
```

But I did not find the build in swap function for signed short.

Is it available in **GCC** or **g++** ?

Comment: As a general rule one should never do bitwise operations on signed types, they might not behave as expected. Just use the unsigned version, and cast as appropriate.

Comment: Just convert to unsigned and back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it available in GCC or g++ ?

No. The list of documented builtins is exhaustive. There are no secret signed bswaps.

On the other hand, there is also hardly any need to use the builtins. Using the bitwise operators is equally fast as the builtins as long as optimiser is enabled, and unlike the GCC builtins, the bitwise operators are standard and work in all compilers.

Note that technically until C++20, your function has implementation defined behaviour when the highest bit of either byte is 1 due to signedness of the argument type. Luckily, all implementations that I know of do what you'd want them to do. Since C++20, the behaviour is standard and the function is unambiguously correct.